# Due to conversion from bitmap to bytebuffer, app is crashing. Is there any problem in tflite model or in bitmap to bytebuffer conversion?

Tags: android, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow-lite

i want to detect sign language from real-time using the mobile camera. I also developed tflite model in kaggle but facing this problem in android studio can anyone help me out??

error in android studio

```
Process: com.example.signtf, PID: 19729
java.nio.BufferOverflowException
    at java.nio.Buffer.nextPutIndex(Buffer.java:514)
    at java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.putFloat(DirectByteBuffer.java:789)
    at com.example.signtf.ClassifierFloatMobileNet.addPixelValue(ClassifierFloatMobileNet.java:60)
    at com.example.signtf.Classifier.convertBitmapToByteBuffer(Classifier.java:222)
    at com.example.signtf.Classifier.recognizeImage(Classifier.java:235)
    at com.example.signtf.ClassifierActivity$1.run(ClassifierActivity.java:99)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
```

### ClassifierActivity.java

```
protected void addPixelValue(int pixelValue) {
    imgData.putFloat((((pixelValue >> 16) & 0xFF) - IMAGE_MEAN) / IMAGE_STD);
    imgData.putFloat((((pixelValue >> 8) & 0xFF) - IMAGE_MEAN) / IMAGE_STD);
    imgData.putFloat(((pixelValue & 0xFF) - IMAGE_MEAN) / IMAGE_STD);
   }
```

### classifier.java

```
/** Writes Image data into a {@code ByteBuffer}. */
private void convertBitmapToByteBuffer(Bitmap bitmap) {
    if (imgData == null) {
        return;
    }
    imgData.rewind();
    bitmap.getPixels(intValues, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
    // Convert the image to floating point.
    int pixel = 0;
    long startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; i < getImageSizeX(); ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < getImageSizeY(); ++j) {
            final int val = intValues[pixel++];
            addPixelValue(val);
        }
    }
    long endTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    LOGGER.v("Timecost to put values into ByteBuffer: " + (endTime - startTime));
}
```

Comment: is the image pixels integer or float ?

Comment: Try using [AndroTF](https://github.com/shubham0204/AndroTF).

Comment: image pixels are in integer

Answer (score 1):

Can you please attached the code of how you create imgData? Since this is a BufferOverflowException issue, I'm guessing imgData is not large enough for the image you try to pass in.

Alternatively, you can try out the [TFLite Support Library](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/lite/experimental/support/java/README.md), which can handle the conversion from bitmap to bytebuffer automatically. See the [example of an image classifier](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/lite/examples/image_classification/android/EXPLORE_THE_CODE.md).